# Max Eigenvalue of A'A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A is an $m\times m$ square matrix with (possibly complex) eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. Suppose $\max |\lambda_i(A)|<r$ (for some positive no. $r$ say). Then can we conclude any upper-bound of $\ \lambda_{\max} (A'A)$ (in terms of $r$) ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $\;A'=A^*=\;$ the adjoint of $\;A\;$ (the transpose conjugate of  $\;A\;$?)

Comment: For the time being let's assume A is real matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are asking is deeply related to the relation between spectral norm $\|A\|_2$ and spectral radius $\rho(A)$. If $\lambda_i$'s are eigenvalues of $A$, then spectral radius is defined as:
$$
\rho(A)=\max|\lambda_i|.
$$
Spectral norm is defined as:
$$
\|A\|_2=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2.
$$
See that $\|Ax\|_2^2=x^*(A^*A)x$ and since $A^*A$ is positive semidefinite, we can see:
$$
\|A\|_2^2= \lambda_{\max}(A^*A).
$$
In general $\|A\|_2\geq \rho(A)$, which means that the upper bound that you have does not tell that much about spectral norm. In general the inequality can be strict.

For instance consider $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
 0&1\\
0&0 \end{array}
\right]$. The eigenvalue is $0$ which give $\rho(A)=0$. However:
 $$
 A^* A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
 0&0\\
1&0  \end{array}
\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
 0&1\\
0&0  \end{array}
\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
 0&0\\
0&1  \end{array}
\right]
$$
which has eigenvalues $0,1$ and hence $\|{{A}}\|_{2}=1$. Hence $\rho(A)<\|A\|_2$.

However for some cases these two are equal. A very general class of these matrices are normal matrices. In this case any upper bound on spectral radius is an upper bound on spectral norm.

---

To see why $\|A\|_2\geq \rho(A)$, pick a unit norm eigenvector $y$ of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue with maximum absolute value. It is easy to see that $\|Ay\|_2=\rho(A)$. From the definition of $\|A\|_2$, we have $\rho(A)\leq \|A\|_2$.

Comment: No, something's wrong here.

Comment: Please care to explain.

Comment: in this step $\|Ax\|_2^2= \lambda_{\max}(A^*A).$, LHS depends on x

Comment: That's right. Just a typo. corrected.

Comment: Yes, and it also I found another post from here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965950/eigenvalue-and-eigenvector-of-aa?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Since $\;\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;A\implies \overline\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;A^*\;$ , and since $\;|\lambda|=|\overline\lambda|\;$we get that

$$\left|\lambda_\max(A^*A)\right|=|\lambda_\max(A)|^2<r^2$$

Comment: I don't get how you write the step $|\lambda_{\max} (A^*A)|=(\max |\lambda_i(A)|)^2$. I know non-zero eigenvalues of AB and BA are same, but I suppose this does not apply here. I am missing something else. Would you please elaborate?